# Assembly Language - push instruction being skipped

Tags: assembly, stack, push, masm

I'm working on an assembly project and for some reason when I go into the debugger and look at this call statement being executed it is skipping the first push statement.

using call statement:

```
push offset strPrompt
push offset strNum
push offset iArray1
call inputArray
add esp, 12
mov iNumOfEntries, eax
```

call statement:

```
inputArray      proc
mov al, al
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
push ebx
push ecx
entryLoop1:
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, 0
invoke putstring, [ebp+16]
invoke getstring, [ebp+12], 10
invoke ascint32, [ebp+12]
jc entryLoop1

cmp eax, -1
je endMethod

mov [[ebp+8][ecx]], eax
add ecx, 4
inc ebx
jmp entryLoop1
endMethod:
mov eax, 0
mov eax, ebx
pop ecx
pop ebx
pop ebp
ret
inputArray endp
```

Comment: Can you provide a disassembly of the assembled code (including the call itself)? (And I see other issues, for example ebx and ebc are reset to zero again and again and the loop is never left)

Comment: Is there a `case` problem with `EBP`? Not familiar with masm specifically, but `EBP != ebp`.

Comment: Insert another line above, for example, mov al , al. let's see if this first line gets executed and if push ebp executes now.

Comment: The problem is with ebp. I normally use the lowercase but i changed it to the uppercase to see if that helped. You never know with assembly.

Comment: After adding in mov al,al:

Comment: The debugger is now off by one. It's not showing the correct next line of code.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes, this is another problem entirely... I'm planning on fixing that after i can get that right operation to execute.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Casing is ignored for registry naming.

Comment: How do you know it is being skipped? Did you dump the first bytes of the stack after its execution?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. masm always did look a bit wonky to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputArray      proc
mov al, al
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
```

When you use the PROC directive the assembler automatically generates the prologue/epilogue code. You should not write it yourself. This could well explain the output of the debugger that you did not expect.

> The assembler automatically generates the prologue code when it encounters the first instruction or label after the PROC directive.
>   The assembler generates the epilogue code when it encounters a RET or IRET instruction.